# OS X Desktop PSD?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I'm looking for an editable PSD of the default OS X desktop so I can use it for app screenshots for the Mac App Store.

P.S. I don't want to take a screenshot of my own desktop. I specifically want the default OS X desktop that you see when you get a new Mac.

Comment: I've never seen anything like this. Why? I imagine it's as easy to get as making a new account, logging in, snapping a screen, and then upping it to Dropbox, Cloudapp, Droplr, whatever. Would take you 30 seconds to do. Once done, delete the new user. This is an utterly lazy question, hence my downvote.

Comment: @cksum Why don't you post this as an answer? Creating a new user account might not be obvious for people coming to OS X from single user systems.

Comment: @cksum It's not laziness. The thought simply didn't occur to me before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have created a layered PSD of the default desktop, at Best for Retina resolution.**

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/tpfxuxpty6p21i1/desktop.psd

Each component of the desktop (Dock, Menu Bar, etc) is a separate layer which can be edited individually.

For instance, parts of the Dock can be shown/hidden:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @MachOSX If you mean did I get this from Dribbble, no, I made this myself. If you mean I should put this on Dribbble, I don't have an invite :(